# Reference request for the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^{\pm 1}\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n^{2\kappa}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request, trigonometric-series

I've consider the following calculations from the so-called Wilker's Inequalities, that I've found in MathWorld, where is mentioned [1] that I add as reference*:

Divide by $\tan(x)$, perform the specialization $x=\frac{1}{n}$ for integers $n\geq 1$, after multiply the inequality by $\frac{1}{n^4}$ and take the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ to state the resulting inequality.

My problem is that I can to prove computationally that $\operatorname{Left side term}<\operatorname{Middle term}$, but my calculations provide me the statement  $$\operatorname{Right side term}<\operatorname{Middle term}.$$

*The purpose of previous paragraph is just to provide motivation and context to my question. Isn't required thus nothing about the mentioned inequality that I should to study in the library of my university.

> **Question.** Do you know if were in the literature closed-form or good approximations of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n^2}\tag{1}$$
>   and/or 
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n^4\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}?\tag{2}$$
>   Then answer this question as a reference request, and I try to find and read those justifications (I don't know if these series are standard to calculate and justify a good approximation). **Many thanks.**

### References:

[1] Borwein, Bailey, and Girgensohn, *Experimentation in Mathematics: Computational Paths to Discovery*, A K Peters/CRC Press (2004).

Comment: the first one is equivalent to $\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(2/n)}{n^2}$

Comment: The first one diverges by the limit test. By the Comparison Test, the second series converges to around $0.83$ by [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+n%3D1+to+infinity+cot(1%2Fn)%2Fn%5E4)

Comment: you can use the Taylor formula on the sine or cotangent function and bound the error term using the formula for the remainder. Both sums are "close" to $\zeta(3)$.

Comment: Alternatively you can use the Euler-Maclaurin formula to approach the series.

Comment: @Masacroso I think I forgot the division sign when putting it into Wolfram! I've now got the correct approximation as $0.63$. Thanks.

Comment: The tail of these series approximates the tail of Apery's constant $\zeta(3)$ as terms are close to $1/n^3$.  Other than its irrationality and numerical evaluation, little is known about Apery's constant.

Comment: Many thanks @TheSimpliFire and Masacroso, and also many thanks much to hardmath. Then I think that both series are convergents.